# How can I give a color to imagecolorallocate?

Tags: php, string, colors, hex

I have a PHP variable which contains information about color. For example `$text_color = "ff90f3"`. Now I want to give this color to `imagecolorallocate`. The `imagecolorallocate` works like that:

`imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);`

So, I am trying to do the following:

```
$r_bg = bin2hex("0x".substr($text_color,0,2));
$g_bg = bin2hex("0x".substr($text_color,2,2));
$b_bg = bin2hex("0x".substr($text_color,4,2));
$bg_col = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bg, $g_bg, $b_bg);
```

It does not work. Why? I try it also without bin2hex, it also did not work. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: what does bin2hex function do?

Comment: I put bin2hex there to transform strings into hexadecimal number which should be given to imagecolorallocate.

Comment: what's the difference between "string" and "hexadecimal number"? And I were asking what this function does, not why did you use it. What does it return at least? In this very case I mean

Comment: If I use it "to transform strings into hexadecimal" than it "transforms strings into hexadecimal". It takes string and returns hexadecimal. It is what it does.

Comment: think what string you feed to this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `hexdec()` (exemple : `hexdec("a0")`)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Answer (score 17):

From http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/gd-hex-resource-imagecolorallocate-265852.html

```
function hexColorAllocate($im,$hex){
    $hex = ltrim($hex,'#');
    $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
    return imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b); 
}
```

Usage

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
$color = hexColorAllocate($img, 'ffff00');
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);
```

the color can be passed as hex `ffffff` or as `#ffffff`

Answer (score 1):

```
function hex2RGB($hexStr, $returnAsString = false, $seperator = ',') {
    $hexStr = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/", '', $hexStr); // Gets a proper hex string
    $rgbArray = array();
    if (strlen($hexStr) == 6) { //If a proper hex code, convert using bitwise operation. No overhead... faster
        $colorVal = hexdec($hexStr);
        $rgbArray['red'] = 0xFF & ($colorVal >> 0x10);
        $rgbArray['green'] = 0xFF & ($colorVal >> 0x8);
        $rgbArray['blue'] = 0xFF & $colorVal;
    } elseif (strlen($hexStr) == 3) { //if shorthand notation, need some string manipulations
        $rgbArray['red'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hexStr, 0, 1), 2));
        $rgbArray['green'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hexStr, 1, 1), 2));
        $rgbArray['blue'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hexStr, 2, 1), 2));
    } else {
        return false; //Invalid hex color code
    }
    return $returnAsString ? implode($seperator, $rgbArray) : $rgbArray; // returns the rgb string or the associative array
}
```