# How merge image on background png image in php

Tags: php, gd

Im using php code to merge user image on png background. Here below is code i am use.

```
$width = 140; 
$height = 140; 
$bottom_image = imagecreatefrompng("bg.png"); 
$top_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("default.jpg"); 
imagesavealpha($top_image, true); 
imagealphablending($top_image, false); 
imagecopyresampled($bottom_image, $top_image, 290, 125, 0, 0, $width,     $height, $width, $height);
//imagecopy($bottom_image, $top_image, 290, 125, 0, 0, $width, $height); 
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($bottom_image);
```

[but i got this result when i save image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfvud.png)

i want user image in round circle back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999251/crop-or-mask-an-image-into-a-circle/999563#999563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying a JPEG image over the background image.

*JPEG doesn't support transparency.*

What you could do with the gd library is:

- Create a new result image of the desired size, then
- Copy the JPEG (user picture) to its center, then
- Copy the partially-transparent PNG background (actually foreground) over result image. The PNG background must have a "transparent window" in the middle so that the user picture doesn't get hidden behind the background (in other words, the white circle part of the background must be transparent).